# How to run Spark-Streaming job as a daemon

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

What is the best way to daemonise the Spark-Streaming job at the same time logging any exception occur in the log file with log-rotation?

Comment: What do you mean by *daemonise the Streaming Job*? Why would one need to do that after scheduling the job with spark-submit?

Comment: with nohup you can achieve this. pls check my answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov What do you mean by `scheduling the job` with spark-submit. You just submit the job to spark. Didn't heard of it that you can schedule it for a particular start time. If you have done it could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Naresh: Below way (which we implemented) useful for you?

Comment: if you are okay you can flagup "accepted by owner"

Comment: @RamPrasadG It seems promising. Though, I haven't tested it. Will do it. Can't i do it simply scheduling the `.sh` file as a `crontab`

Comment: Please note as an additional information, Flume agents also run in the same way :-) we have done in flume as well as spark streaming. Both are working fine

Comment: spark-submit in cluster mode and supervise will achieve this . It will schedule the driver in some worker node and supervise flag will restart the job on failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the way to run 2 daemon threads, based on your requirement it
>   can increase..

```
nohup ./mysparkstreamingjob.sh one> ../../logs/nohup.out 2> ../../logs/nohup.err < /dev/null &

nohup ./mysparkstreamingjob.sh two> ../../logs/nohup.out 2> ../../logs/nohup.err < /dev/null &
```

***mysparkstreamingjob.sh will look like***

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $CLASSPATH
spark-submit --verbose --jars $(echo /dirofjars/*.jar | tr ' ' ','),$SPARK_STREAMING_JAR --class com.xx.xx.StreamingJob \
    --master yarn-client \
    --num-executors 12 \
    --executor-cores 4 \
    --driver-memory 4G \
    --executor-memory 4G \
    --driver-class-path ../../config/properties/* \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M" \
    --conf "spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.5" \
    --conf "spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.75" \
    --conf "spark.storage.unrollFraction=0.2" \
    --conf "spark.memory.fraction=0.75" \
    --conf "spark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true" \
    --conf "spark.worker.cleanup.interval=14400" \
    --conf "spark.shuffle.io.numConnectionsPerPeer=5" \
    --conf "spark.eventlog.enabled=true" \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraLibrayPath=$HADOOP_HOME/*:$HBASE_HOME/*:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:$HBASE_HOME/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:$HDFS_PATH/*:$SOLR_HOME/*:$SOLR_HOME/lib/*" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=$HADOOP_HOME/*:$HBASE_HOME/*:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:$HBASE_HOME/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:$HDFS_PATH/*:$SOLR_HOME/*:$SOLR_HOME/lib/*" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=$(echo /dirofjars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')" \
    --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048" \
    --conf "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1024" \
    --conf "spark.eventLog.overwrite=true" \
    --conf "spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true" \
    --conf "spark.akka.frameSize=1024" \
    --files xxxx.properties, xxxx.properties \
    -DprocMySpark$1
```

Custom log4j rotation of file you need to configure and pass that setting to your spark submit. based on appender you use it will do in natural way as java + log4j working.

For Example :

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=/tmp/log4j.properties"
```

Moreover, spark webui url(which is by default) has all logs high level and low level

Answer (score 0):

You should be using oozie for scheduling your spark streaming job. 
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html

This will give you a good overview about scheduling, managing and monitoring your spark jobs.
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/new-hue-demos-spark-ui-job-browser-oozie-scheduling-and-yarn-support/